# How do I access the HttpEvent progress for file upload in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

I have been through the angular.io docs as well as other SO answers on this however I still cant wrap my head around how to access file upload progress for my POST call from Angular 5 to NodeJS and display to the user.

Here is what I am doing.

//Component Code: body is the form data that has a file and a few other fields.

```
  this.fileService.uploadtool5(body, this.token).subscribe(res =>{

        if(res.success){
          //do something server has received post data
        }
      },(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
              // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
              //console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
              //console.log('Status', err.status);
             // this.signupfailreasonstatus = err.status;
            } else {
              // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
              // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
              //console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
              //console.log('Status', err.status);
            }
      });
```

//I have an interceptor for the response object which looks like this.

```
export interface Tool9Response {
  success: boolean;
  message: string;
}
```

//fileService code

```
uploadtool5( payload, token ) : Observable<Tool9Response>{
       const httpOptions = {
         headers: new HttpHeaders({
           'Authorization': token
         })
       };
       return this.http.post<Tool9Response>(this._baseURL + 'appsecuritydesign', payload, httpOptions);

   }
```

Most of the files that I am uploading are 100+ MB for processing so upload takes time and I want to show the upload progress. How do I access the HttpEvent progress for the file upload without changing how I am currently posting the data to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your fileService code:

```
uploadtool5( payload, token ) : Observable<any> { // Assuming `payload` is FormData 

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
       'Authorization': token
     })


   const req = new HttpRequest(
        'POST',      
         this._baseURL + 'appsecuritydesign', 
         payload, 
         { 
            headers:headers,
            reportProgress: true //This is required for track upload process
         }
   );

   return this.http.request(req);
 }
```

// component

```
this.fileService.uploadtool5(body, this.token).subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {

   if (event.type == HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
   {
     console.log("Loading: "+ event.loaded / (event.total || event.loaded) * 100 + '%');
   }
   if (event.type == HttpEventType.Response) {
     console.log("response:", event);
    /*success and message fields from the response can be accessed 
      here like this*/
     console.log("response:", event);
     console.log("body:", event.body);
     console.log("success:", event.body.success);
     console.log("message:", event.body.message);
   }


  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Ritwick. However, notice the response intercept I mentioned in the question Tool9Response. when event.type is HttpEventType.Response how do i use the interceptor?

Comment: This works with a little tweak. Thank you. updating your answer with edits.

Comment: Yes! event.body is the response object.

Comment: Give a try with `(event: HttpEvent<Tool9Response >)` for type checking.

Comment: Suppose, UploadProgress event ongoing and user want to cancel it then?